# Game that this piece comes from?

Tags: identify-this-game

I’m trying to figure out what game this piece comes from. I only have two pieces, but apparently they are different shapes and colors. It almost looks like a rock. Size is about half of dime:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: All of the pictures are very blurry. Could you try again, please? You might be trying to take the picture from too close to the object. Try from further away (and crop if you need to), and wait for the camera to focus.

Comment: To me these look like pieces of plastic that have been chipped of from something bigger. What makes you think these are from a game?

Comment: My aunt does an annual holiday "card"...usually a riddle or some kind of puzzle to figure out. This year was "Name the Game" and we got a tin full of game pieces that you had to figure out where they came from...Candy Land, Clue, Monopoly, Operation...this is the only piece no one can figure out! So that's how I know it's for a game. We only have until January 1st, so running out of time haha. Got desperate and decided to try a game forum. I can try uploading a clearer picture :)

Comment: Are the pieces plastic? If they are actual stones, they might come from a Crystal Mining Kit: https://www.google.com/search?q=crystal+mining+kit&safe=active&tbm=isch
P.S. Thanks for adding some context to the Q. That's a cool Aunt. =)

Comment: Did you find out what game it was?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it ended up being from "Magic Rocks." Not sure if that's exactly a game, but that's what it was!!

[image: Magic Rocks Kit]

Comment: If you're the same Sarah who asked the question, you can contact Stack Exchange to [have your accounts merged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way you can even accept your own answer.